# Cannot set DynamiResource on Fallback

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a multilanguage application and I'm trying to set as Fallbackvalue a Dynamic resource in this way:

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeProperty, FallbackValue='{DynamicResource somekEY}'" />
```

this will throw an exception:

> You can set 'DynamicResourceExtension' for the 'StringFormat' type 'Binding' property. You can set 'DynamicResourceExtension' only for a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

how can handle this situation?

Comment: Sorry, copy and paste error, check now

Comment: `DynamicResource` is a shortcut for a `Binding`, and you can't bind properties of `Binding`. You'll need `PriorityBinding` instead.

Comment: @DaveM could you add an example? I didn't know this sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `DynamicResource` works like a binding. You can't bind properties of `Binding` itself (or anything that isn't a `DependecyProperty` as stated in the error message). You actually see the same sort of error message when you try to do that with a binding: (e.g. `{Binding SomeProperty, FallbackValue={Binding SomeOtherProperty}}`)

This is where `PriorityBinding` comes in. It allows specifying a series of fallback values as bindings themselves. With `PriorityBinding` you specify a list of Bindings, the first binding with a valid value is the one used. Ideally we could write something like this:

```
 <TextBlock>
   <TextBlock.Text>
     <PriorityBinding>
       <Binding Path="SomeProperty" />
       <DynamicResource ResourceKey="somekEY" />
     </PriorityBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>
```

Unfortunately, `DynamicResourceExtension` can't directly be converted to a binding to be used in a PriorityBinding (or MultiBinding) like the above, so we'll have to use a little trick instead (the example above won't work). We'll use the `Tag` property (which is a property that has no effect and is basically for holding  values for tricks like this) to capture the value of the DynamicResource, and then use a RelativeSource binding in the `PriorityBinding` to get it:

```
 <TextBlock Tag="{DynamicResource somekEY}">
   <TextBlock.Text>
     <PriorityBinding>
       <Binding Path="SomeProperty" />
       <Binding Path="Tag" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
     </PriorityBinding>
   </TextBlock.Text>
 </TextBlock>
```

Comment: All this code for set a fallback with a dynamic resource?

Comment: Well you could write a custom markup extension and/or a custom implementation of Binding to make it a little less painful

Comment: but how your code solve the situation? I need to set as fallbackvalue a resource available in a dictionary

Comment: see updated answer, I tried to explain further how it works

Comment: could you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48743504/how-to-set-a-dynamicresource-as-prioritybinding